# SQL avoid duplicate being inserted into staging/temp table

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a site that handles uploads of CSV files and inserts them to the DB. The CSV templates are 229 fields, with multiple rows per file. Since there are multiple rows, there may be times that two CSV files have a record from a previous file and I want to avoid duplicates.

I have the CSV files currently being uploaded into a 230 field staging table (one more field than the CSV for an auto incrementing primary key), and then they split into smaller tables.

My issue: when the CSV is uploaded I want any records that already exist to overwrite or ignore so that I only have one of each 229 field record.

Is there a way to do this just on the staging table so I don't have to worry about the smaller tables?

Comment: Have you looked at the [on duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax? Unless i am mistaken, that's what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your previously imported records are in the temp table, you could use something like this:

```
select *
from `table`
group by Col1, Col2, Col3 [,...]
having count(*) = 1
order by id asc;
```

Basically, select all the records, then group them by each column which you want to distinct them, and filter the result by the group count (where the group count > 1 there is a multiple of the same records).
After this, you only have to filter out the newly added records.

But keep in mind, if there is a possibility of duplicates in the same csv file, they going to be skipped by this method. If that's the case, you can use distinct first for your dataset.

Comment: I think I was originally leaning toward distinct first, just because there are so many fields. It's strange, but these CSV files all have several rows, each with 229 fields so for sake of ease I have each one importing to a 230 field staging table and then splitting to smaller ones. Since we're testing with one CSV right now, it keeps filling up every time we upload and we have to truncate. Could I use distinct first in a way that checks multiple fields? LIke, if workorder number, serial number, account number and date are the same?

Comment: @TomN. The distinct only applies the fields present in the result set. So if you want to distinct by all the columns you have to use `select distinct *` and if you only want to distinct by a couple of fields then use `select distinct field1, field2, filed3 [, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

First load data from the file into a temp_table and then run a query

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table INTO target_table 
WHERE temp_table.value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM target_table)
```

Here temp_table.value is the value by which you define if the rows you copy already exist in a target_table